# CString.Format with variable float precision

Tags: c++, string, mfc, floating-point

I have a float value: (`data->val`) which could be of three possible float precisions: `%.1f`, `%.2f` and `%.3f` how would I format it using `CString::Format` to dsiplay only the number of decimal points necessary? eg:

```
CString sVal;

sVal.Format(L"%.<WHAT GOES HERE?>f", data->val);
if(stValue)
    stValue->SetWindowText(sVal);
```

As in I don't want any additional zeros on the end of my formatted string.

Comment: Not sure I understand, why not just use %.3f

Comment: Necessary for what? to reinterpret the string as the same float value?

Comment: I don't wnat any extra 0s on the end.

Comment: Perhaps are you looking for `%g` or `%.*f`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you know the precision you'd like simply use [`%.*f` and supply the precision as an integer argument to `CString::Format`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ecbz014.aspx). If you'd like the simplest effective representation, try `%g`:

```
int precision = 2; // whatever you figure the precision to be
sVal.Format(L"%.*f", precision, data->val);
// likely better: sVal.Format(L"%g", data->val);
```

Comment: Yeah I ended up specifying the precision as an integer value in the data 's struct then using this method, cheers mate.

Answer (score 1):

its some time ago, but maybe this will work...

```
CString getPrecisionString(int len)
{
   CString result;
   result.format( "%s%d%s","%.", len, "f" );
   return result;
}

// somewhere else
CString sVal;

sVal.Format(getPrecisionString(2), data->val);
if(stValue)
    stValue->SetWindowText(sVal);
```

the other way is, to cut the '0's just after adding the %.3f value with

```
sVal.trimEnd('0')
```

but is dangerous cuz you may have the '.' at the end...